# Refresh div if a child div is added or removed?

Tags: jquery

I've made a function which updates a specific div every 3 seconds. But what I am trying to do is I want to detect change in a div. When the div class ".dock-container" gets a new child div, or a child div is removed I want to reload the div, regardless of what the child div is called. If nothing is changed, no new child div added, nothing should happen.

This is what I got now, this updates the div automatically every 3 seconds:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  function autoRefresh() {
    $.ajax({
      success: function(data) {
        var result = $('<div />').append(data).find('.dock-container').html();
        $('.dock-container').html(result);
      }
    });
  }
  autoRefresh();
  // Refresh at page load and every 3000 milliseconds / 3 seconds
  var auto_refresh = setInterval(autoRefresh, 3000);
})
```

EDIT: I tried using Mozilla's example:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  // Select the node that will be observed for mutations
  var targetNode = document.getElementsByClassName('dock-container');

  // Options for the observer (which mutations to observe)
  var config = { attributes: true, childList: true };

  // Callback function to execute when mutations are observed
  var callback = function(mutationsList) {
      for(var mutation of mutationsList) {
          if (mutation.type == 'childList') {
              console.log('A child node has been added or removed.');
          }
      }

  };
  var observer = new MutationObserver(callback);
  observer.observe(targetNode[0], config);
})
```

This is the div's child I want to detect if they are removed or added:

```
<div class="dock-container">
      <div id="widget-clock-widget-15" class="dock-element widget_widget-clock-widget" style="width:50%"><div class="clock"><div class="clock-time"><span class="clock-hours">test 1</span></div></div></div>
      <div id="widget-clock-widget-26" class="dock-element widget_widget-clock-widget" style="width:50%"><div class="clock"><div class="clock-time"><span class="clock-hours">test 2</span></div></div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should take a look into MutationObservers https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Comment: I tried using the example given here, check the first post with the updated code. But I cannot make it work at all.

Comment: You're using the example but missed out the most important part: creating the new observer. Also, you are adding observer to a dynamically-created element.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, how should it be done?

Comment: @joq3 You should make those additions too. `var observer = new MutationObserver(callback);` this is how you instantiate new MutationObserver. Then you start observing via this code; `observer.observe(targetNode, config);` . Add them after callback definition. But since `document.getElementsByClassName` returns array, you should say `targetNode[0]`

Comment: Thank  you, I updated the first post. But I still cannot see anything in the log when a new child div in dock-container is added or removed. I added the html, showing the parent div dock-container and the child divs, which I want to track if they are added or removed.